# Delete using background color Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm completely noob in Photoshop, I don't know how can I do this fast:

Press M, select region, press delete, choose with foreground color, click OK

It will be nice if I coud just need this steps:

Press M, select region, press delete

Can I make the delete action apply 'fill with background color' immediately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cmd + Backspace does that on Mac.
And Ctrl + Backspace on Windows.

Comment: You don't need the delete key, instead as Jon suggested press CTRL+Backspace for background color. For Forground color ALT+Backspace.